# getting the latest data from prisma client by id

Tags: javascript, node.js, prisma

```
datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

model Data {
  id        Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  longitude Float
  latitude  Float
  distance  Int
}
```

How can I get the latest data by id? 
I am using @prisma/client and postgresql.

Comment: You can use [order by aggregate function](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#orderby) for this since your `Data` `id` is autoincrementing

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "latest"? Do you mean: 1. the data records that were created most recently OR 2. Data records that were most recently updated OR 3. Data records with the highest ID (would be same as most recently created since your IDs are auto incrementing).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically you just want to order data by `id` in descending order?

Here we go:

```js
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

const data = await prisma.data.findMany({ orderBy: { id: 'desc' } });
```